# Use homebrew to install applications to virtual enviornment

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

Is there anyway I can use homewbrew to install packages (like numpy or matplotlib) into isolated virtual environments created using virtualenv, without having the packaged installed system wide.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pip` inside of the `virtualenv` and it will isolate the packages to just that `virtualenv`. Each `virtualenv` has a local version of `pip` and will install the packages locally.

Comment: I normally do, but some packages (like numpy) require homebrew (pip dosent work). Is there anyway to install into the virtualenv using homebrew?

Comment: I can install numpy using pip on OS X - what platform are you on?

Answer (score 1):

You can install numpy with pip.

Your problem will probably solved by issuing the following commands:

```
$ export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
$ export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
$ pip install numpy
```

You can test with

```
$ python -c 'import numpy'
```

There are several packages which have this problem at the moment. PIL is another example.